# Protractor Cucumber BDD Tests Show Pass before Execution

Tags: javascript, cucumber, protractor, bdd

I have a sample BDD test using Protractor with Cucumber. On executing the code, the console immediately shows the result as passed and the code actually begins executing only after that.

I wish execution status display to be in sync with actual execution.(e.g Console displays - '*Given I launch the protractor demo page*' and the code underneath is executed, then console displays next step and so on) I know it has got something to do with Async coding and callbacks, not able to figure out the exact problem though.

Feature file:

```
Feature: Test
Scenario:  Test Scenario
    Given I launch the protractor demo page
    When I enter two in the first field
    And I enter three in the second field
    And I click Go button
    Then Result should be displayed as Five
```

Step File:

```
 var chai = require('chai');
    var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    var expect = chai.expect;

    module.exports = function () {


        this.Given(/^I launch the protractor demo page$/, function (callback) {
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
            browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

            browser.getTitle().then(function(text){
               console.log('title is - ' + text);
                expect(text).to.equal('Super Calculator');
            });
         callback();
        });

        this.When(/^I enter two in the first field$/, function (callback) {
            element(by.model('first')).sendKeys('2');
            callback();
        });

        this.When(/^I enter three in the second field$/, function (callback) {
            element(by.model('second')).sendKeys('3');
            callback();
        });

        this.When(/^I click Go button$/, function (callback) {
            element(by.id('gobutton')).click();
            callback();
        });

        this.Then(/^Result should be displayed as Five$/, function (callback) {
             element(by.repeater('result in memory')).all(by.tagName('td')).get(2).getText().then(function(text){
            expect(text).to.equal('5');
            });
            callback();
        });

    };
```

Comment: protractor version is 3.3.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You need to either `return` a promise or use the `done` callback in your step definitions. Otherwise cucumber doesn't know when your asynchronous
>   actions are complete.

I had the same question and above statement was the response from one of the core members of the `protractor-cucumber` github forum.

I prefer to `return` promises when I am performing some actions on the results with `.then` function and use `.done` callback function when I am not, Also you don't need `callbacks` now `CucumberJS` supports promises. So your step file should look like -

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function () {


    this.Given(/^I launch the protractor demo page$/, function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

      return browser.getTitle().then(function(text){
           console.log('title is - ' + text);
            expect(text).to.equal('Super Calculator');
        });
    });

    this.When(/^I enter two in the first field$/, function () {
       return element(by.model('first')).sendKeys('2'); 
    });

    this.When(/^I enter three in the second field$/, function () {
       return element(by.model('second')).sendKeys('3'); // you can use return also
    });

    this.When(/^I click Go button$/, function () {
        return element(by.id('gobutton')).click();
    });

    this.Then(/^Result should be displayed as Five$/, function () {
        return element(by.repeater('result in memory')).all(by.tagName('td')).get(2).getText().then(function(text){
        expect(text).to.equal('5');
        });

    });

};
```

I would recommend you to read about `Promises` http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ as it requires some understanding how they behave.They can be sometimes tricky, it took me a while to get an idea still I have lot to learn :)

Comment: Tried the solution given by @igniteram1. The first two steps execute as before i.e they show pass even before the actual execution has begun.. Going to the third step the script errors with message 'function timed out after 5000 ms'

Comment: that's strange, try increasing your default timeout and use return in first 2  steps as well

Comment: I updated my answer, you should not use maximize and get url in your steps, those should be part of `onPrepare` or `before` hooks

Comment: Glad it worked ! Please accept the answer as it would help others who have the same question :)