# Protractor: Why cucumber steps shows as executed before the actual execution happened

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am new to protractor-cucumber. I am trying to execute below step definition from protractor conf.js.

```
this.Given(/^I go to sparqHomePage$/, function (callback) {

  homepage.goToHomePage()
  homepage.login(data[0].UserName,data[0].Password).then(callback);

});

this.Then(/^I create a process$/, function () {

  homepage.clickDesign();
  homepage.clickFlowDesigner();
  console.log(params.flow.procName + ' '+  params.flow.procDesc);
  designPage.createNewProc(params.flow.procName, params.flow.procDesc);

});

this.Then(/^I should see process is saved in db$/, function (callback) {

    var sql = "select * from process where name = ?";
    sql = mysql.format(sql, params.flow.procName);
    console.log(sql);

    dbConn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields){

        if(!err) {
            procDbObj = rows;
            console.log(rows);
            expect(procDbObj[0].name).to.eventually.equal( params.flow.procName);
            expect(procDbObj[0].description).to.eventually.equal(params.flow.procDesc).and.notify(callback);
        }
    });
});
```

As soon as I start the execution, the console log shows, feature file execution was completed, but the actual execution is not yet completed.

In my 3rd step I am doing some db validation based on the step 1 and step 2 actions. As cucumber trying to execute all the steps before the completion of real execution with browser, my 3rd test is always failing.

How can I make cucumber to wait for step execution is completed before moving to the next step.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405184/protractor-cucumber-bdd-tests-show-pass-before-execution

Answer (score 1):

You are calling 
`homepage.goToHomePage()` and `homepage.login(data[0].UserName,data[0].Password).then(callback);`. Are both methods correct promises that are correctly handled? It now looks like it is calling both methods but giving a direct `callback` before resolving the promise.

<strike>As Ross stated, you can also chain the promises, but first be sure the promises are correctly handled</strike>

**Edit:**

As Ross stated, you can also chain the promises, but first be sure the promises are correctly handled.

You can also return the promise in stead of the callback, just use it as this

```
this.Given(/^I go to sparqHomePage$/, function () {
  homepage.goToHomePage();
  return homepage.login(data[0].UserName,data[0].Password);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
homepage.goToHomePage()
homepage.login(data[0].UserName,data[0].Password).then(callback);
```

I'm not sure exactly what is happening in the first line but I assume thats going to be doing a click, you will need to make that return a promise and re-write it like

```
homepage.goToHomePage().then(()=>{
    homepage.login(data[0].UserName,data[0].Password).then(callback);
})
```

And then follow this pattern for the rest of your code as I can see this same issue throughout