# Protractor Cucumber Tests is Passed even after assert Fail

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs, allure

Iam running Protractor-Cucumber Tests. On execution the console immediately shows the result as passed and the code actually begins executing only after that(which is normal behaviour with async and sync)

I know it is issue with Async, promises and callbacks and also tried the solution available on [Protractor Cucumber BDD Tests Show Pass before Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405184/protractor-cucumber-bdd-tests-show-pass-before-execution?rq=1) but couldn't succeed, below is the console output and also Allure-report shows step as PASSED

```
1 scenario ([32m1 passed[39m)
2 steps ([32m2 passed[39m)
0m00.023s
E/launcher - expected 'Individual' to equal 'Individua'
E/launcher - AssertionError: expected 'Individual' to equal 'Individua'
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

and below the Chai assert
expect(page.getCustomerName().getSelectedText()).to.eventually.equal("Individua");

getSelectedText method selects first dropdown value and returns promise

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Can you paste your script here, because if you also tried the solution posted in the link you provided there is something else wrong

Comment: Have you returned your expect statement?

Comment: Below is the code..

this.When(/^I login a new page$/, function() {
    console.log("Loggin in");

          browser.waitForAngular();

    homePage = new HomePage();
          page = homePage.getCustomerDetails();


          return expect(page.getCustomerName().getSelectedText()).to.eventually.equal("Individua");

   });

Comment: return statement as in the code straightaway fails by closing browser..

Comment: Can you check your xml file if this step is failed or not? bcoz allure reports consume the xml and generate the results .

Comment: xml file shows PASSED for this step

<step start="1497262603405" stop="1497262603417" status="passed">
     <name>I login a new page</name>
     <title>I login a new page</title>
     <attachments>
     </attachments>
     <steps>
     </steps>
    </step>

Test halts with Assertion fail, but xml doesn't show the result as 'Failed' , i tried with Callbacks also with .and.notify(callback); still passes

Comment: Can somebody help me in resolving this issue..